# Зависимость проходимого расстояния от скорости Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика

Ведем пальцем по тачпаду, получаем разницу от точки касания до текущей точки пальца. 
Относительно размера экрана приводим это значение к промежутку от -1 до +1

```
 if(th.phase == TouchPhase.Began && (th.phase != TouchPhase.Moved))
                {
                    StartTouchPos = th.position;
                }
if (th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    currentpositiony = (((CurrentTouchPos.y - StartTouchPos.y) / Screen.height)) + savey;
                }
if(th.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    savey = currentpositiony;
                }
```

Как к этому прикрутить зависимость от скорости движения пальца по тачу?
Чтобы, когда пальцем ведёшь быстрее, значение currentpositiony менялось быстрее.

Для наглядности - так же работает мышка. Ведёте медленно - за 10 см движение мышки на столе её курсор двигается на часть экрана. Дернете быстро - за 10 см на столе курсор пробежит весь экран.

Скорость у нас вычисляется так

```
 distance = th.deltaPosition.magnitude;

 speed = distance / Time.deltaTime;
```

Вроде простая математика, а никак решение в голову не приходит.

Answer (score 2):

У тебя есть расстояние. Почему бы не засекать время еще в момент старта тача?
А расстояние/время = скорость.

Далее закидаешь эту скорость в некую функцию (Скорей всего пол параболы как правая чать параболы на картинке) ( если что, подберешь какую более удачную)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [wordsland.ru](http://wordsland.ru/mfi/img/parabola/par1.gif))</sub>

И эта функция будет возвращать скорость движения твоего персонажа в игре так как тебе нужно.
Чем ответ не подходит?